# Angular Directive - Adding an anchor dynamically the click doesn't fire in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive code that creates an anchor tag with the purpose of downloading some csv content. It works well in both Chrome and Firefox but not in IE 11 or Edge.   Is there something wrong with what I am doing here?    Thoughts on a better way? Any clues would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
     function link(scope, element, attrs) {

            // var el = element[0];
            element.bind('click', function(e){
                //var table = e.target.nextElementSibling;
                var table = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#' + scope.exportTable ) )[0];
                var csvString = '';
                for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length;i++){
                    var rowData = table.rows[i].cells;
                    for(var j=0; j<rowData.length;j++){
                        csvString = csvString + _.replace(rowData[j].innerHTML,',','') + ",";
                    }
                    csvString = csvString.substring(0,csvString.length - 1);
                    csvString = csvString + "\n";
                }
                csvString = csvString.substring(0, csvString.length - 1);

                var anchorElement = document.createElement('a');


                var anchor = angular.element(anchorElement);
                anchor.attr({
                    style: 'display:none',
                    href: 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa(csvString),
                    download: scope.exportFilename
                });

                document.body.appendChild(anchorElement);
                anchorElement.click();
                anchor.remove();
            });
    }
```

Comment: What's the length of your data url?  There are limitations that vary based on browsers, which is likely what you're running into.

Comment: Great thought - will check it out as soon as I have a chance.   Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply Joseph. That was totally it.   Cheers, Bruce